# RecyclerView inside LinearLayout removes clickability of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-recyclerview

I have a `LinearLayout` that has a `RecyclerView` inside it. The `LinearLayout` is clickable until add the `RecyclerView` inside it, and if I remove the `RecyclerView` it becomes clickable again.

I have tried all combinations of `android:clickable`, `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` and nothing works.

I need the `RecyclerView` inside the `LinearLayout` and I have to be able to click the `LinearLayout` and have an `OnClick` event handler.

Comment: Share the code till you have tried. It will help to rectify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line of code to my LinearLayout:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

This solved the problem.